# replace column names from one df with the rows from the other df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

df1:

| word | merged |
| --- | --- |
| green | positive_green |
| green energy | positive_green_energy |
| jets | negative_jets |
| green hydrogen | positive_green_hydrogen |
| renewable energy | positive_renewable_energy |

df2:

| column1 | column2 | green | green energy | jets | green hydrogen | renewable energy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xx | xx | xx | xx | xx | xx | xx |

I would like to replace columns' names in the df2 to the ones from df1 (rows from df1 matching columns with df2 and replace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.rename`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) with dictionary:

```
df2 = df2.rename(columns=dict(zip(df1.word, df1.merged)))
```